# Difference between report subscriptions showing in ReportServer vs SSRS web view

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am currently working on a master list of all the reports run for my company as well as all subscriptions for those reports. I have come across an issue where a subscription is showing on the SSRS web view for that report, but is not listed in the dbo.subscriptions table in SSMS. I would not have even known there was a subscription on these reports except that I went through and matched up my list of reports with the dbo.executionlogstorage table.

I have also noticed that some of the reports that show up in the dbo.subscriptions table do not show any subscriptions in the SSRS web view.

I am trying to understand what the difference is between these subscriptions. My initial theory is that it has something to do with subscriptions being set up in the SSRS web view vs SSMS, but I have not been able to verify this.